# Syrian refugee in Germany: Visit Ireland after being denied once

Tags: germany, ireland, refugees, deportation, syrian-citizens

I am a Syrian refugee in Germany. Last year I wanted to visit Ireland, but at the airport they did not let me in as they said intentions for visiting Ireland were not genuine. Can I try to visit Ireland again?

Comment: If you are refused permission to enter you must be given the reasons [in writing](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/moving_to_ireland/coming_to_live_in_ireland/permission_to_land_in_ireland.html).

Comment: I'm confused.
I'm not sure what the laws are like in Germany but from what I gather refugees should be allowed to travel between countries (https://www.quora.com/Which-countries-can-a-refugee-with-a-5-year-leave-to-remain-in-the-UK-travel-to-without-a-visa-on-a-Convention-Travel-Document-issued-by-the-UK) but then I've been told by a friend in Spain that his cleaning lady is a refugee and hasn't left the country in 10 years because due to her status she can't. Any clarification?

Comment: @theotherone refugees don't have greater rights to travel than others, of course, and *anyone* can be denied entry by a passport inspector unless that person is a citizen of the country. EU citizens have greater rights of entry to other EU countries, but even those rights are subject to limitation on certain grounds, and they don't apply to non-EU citizens or refugees.

Comment: In a lot of cases in Germany, refugees with asylum status are not allowed to leave Germany or they forfeit their asylum. Sometimes they even require permission to leave the city they have been assigned (this might be out of date).

Comment: @simbabque That is not true if the person has been recognized as a refugee and granted asylum. During the processing of the request for asylum or if the request has been denied, but immediate deportation is not possible, travel restrictions may be (and are usually) imposed.

Comment: What kind of travel document did you use and what was the exact reason for refusing entry? Until you answer, I vote to close the question as unclear.

Answer (score 3):

YES you can try to visit again. That does not mean anything will change, you can still be denied entry if your circumstances have not changed and it is determined you still do not qualify for entry.

Make sure you don't have a ban. Review the document you were given when denied entry.

Comment: its important for me to know, how can i be sure? thanks

Answer (score 2):

The status of refugees in Germany can differ:

- Persons who have been granted political asylum.
- Persons who have been granted protection under the Geneva refugee rules.
- Persons who have been denied refugee status and who are legally obliged to leave, but haven't done so.
- Persons whose application is under review, or who have not yet exhausted all possible appeals against a negative decision.
- Persons who have not formally applied yet because the BAMF hasn't got to their case yet.

Those whose status is not yet settled may come under the [Dublin III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dublin_Regulation) regulation. While in Germany, their travel may even be limited to a [single administrative district](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residenzpflicht).

*Generally speaking they will always have a right to **leave** the EU, but no right to **travel within** the EU or even within a member state.*

Comment: If the OP is recognized as a refugee (and the question seem to imply so), he might very well have the right to travel to other Schengen and/or EU countries. A German refugee travel document is accepted by Ireland for visa-free entry.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, quite a lot of Syrians are still in the process, which notoriously takes years.

Comment: A few municipalities are indeed very slow when processing asylum requests, but the average processing time in Germany is 'only' 7 months, even after it increased significantly due to the refugee surge in the late 2015 and beginning of 2016. According to the last numbers I've seen, about 5% of the requests take longer to process than 18 months, Most of these cases are minors, where their claimed age is disputed leading to long delays while waiting for a medical examination.